# Drag&Drop Изображение накладывается поверх другого изображения

Tags: html, css, drag-n-drop

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

function check() {
  const parent = document.querySelector('#div2')
  const child = document.querySelector('#drag2')
  const result = parent.contains(child)

  document.getElementById('resulttext').innerHTML = result ? '' : '';
}
```

```css
#div1,
#div2 {
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

img.imgelem1 {
  width: 50px;
}

img.imgelem2 {
  width: 50px;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="imgtd">
      <div class="imgcontainer">
        <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c631419/v631419862/e15e/xQ6lvNfmtvs.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1">
        <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c631419/v631419862/e15e/xQ6lvNfmtvs.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1">
        <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c631419/v631419862/e15e/xQ6lvNfmtvs.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2">
        <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c631419/v631419862/e15e/xQ6lvNfmtvs.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button class="buttonresult" onclick="check();">CHECK</button>
<p id="resulttext"></p>
```

Накладываются изображение при перекидывании, если случайно поверх другой картинки поставить, как можно это исправить?